# Pairs with relations

Tags: field-theory, permutations, finite-fields, permutation-cycles

Let $\mathrm{p}$ be a prime number at least three and let $\mathrm{k}$ be a positive integer smaller than $\mathrm{p}$. Given $\mathrm{a}_1, \ldots, \mathrm{a}_{\mathrm{k}} \in \mathbb{F}_{\mathrm{p}}$ and distinct elements $\mathrm{b}_1, \ldots, \mathrm{b}_{\mathrm{k}} \in \mathbb{F}_{\mathrm{p}}$, prove that there exists a permutation $\sigma$ of $[\mathrm{k}]$ such that the values of $\mathrm{a}_{\mathrm{i}}+\mathrm{b}_{\sigma(\mathrm{i})}$ are distinct modulo $\mathrm{p}$.

I am not sure if the below solution logic contains fallacy or not, but this is my progress so far:

We will prove this by induction on $k$.

**Base Case**:

Let's start with the case where $k=1$.

We only have one possible permutation here, $\sigma(1) = 1$, and since $a_1, b_1 \in \mathbb{F}_p$, $a_1 + b_1 \mod p$ is unique. So, the claim holds for $k=1$.

**Induction Step**:

Assume that the claim holds for some $k < p$. We will show that it also holds for $k+1$.

Consider $k+1$ values of $a$ and $b$, denoted as $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{k+1}$ and $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_{k+1}$.

For every permutation $\sigma$ of $[k]$, $a_i + b_{\sigma(i)}$ are distinct modulo $p$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$ by our induction hypothesis.

Now, we consider the value $a_{k+1} + b_i$ for each $i \in [k+1]$. If for every $i$, $a_{k+1} + b_i \mod p$ is different from all $a_j + b_{\sigma(j)} \mod p$ where $j \in [k]$, then we can simply append $i$ to the permutation $\sigma$ to form a permutation of $[k+1]$, and we are done.

Otherwise, suppose that there exists an $i$ such that $a_{k+1} + b_i \equiv a_j + b_{\sigma(j)} \mod p$ for some $j \in [k]$. We can write this as $a_{k+1} - a_j \equiv b_{\sigma(j)} - b_i \mod p$.

Because $a_{k+1} \neq a_j$ and $b_i$ is distinct from $b_{\sigma(j)}$, the quantity $a_{k+1} - a_j$ is distinct from $b_{\sigma(j)} - b_i$ in the field $\mathbb{F}_p$, thus they cannot be equivalent. This contradiction shows that such an $i$ cannot exist, and that there always exists a permutation $\sigma$ of $[k+1]$ such that $a_i + b_{\sigma(i)}$ are distinct modulo $p$.

Therefore, by the principle of mathematical induction, the claim holds for all $k < p$.

Comment: Haven't read all of this, but your third sentence in the Induction Step section seems problematic:  "For every permutation $\sigma$ of $[k]\cdots $".  That's *not* the induction hypothesis, or at least it shouldn't be.  The claim just asks us to show that there exists some $\sigma $ that gets the job done.  Clearly it isn't true that all permutations get the job done...say $a_i=-b_i$.  Then, for $\sigma  = id$, $a_i+b_i=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for pointing this out. Yes, you are correct! Do you know how to fix this issue? Induction was the only way I was thinking about

Comment: Induction seems like a good idea, but you'll have to just use the single permutation you are sure of.  Of course, you can vary which $k$ you use out of the $k+1$, so that should help.

Comment: @lulu Could you please elaborate on it? I could not understand what you mean. If it is a full solution, can you make it detailed please?

Comment: I haven't got a full proof in mind (it's not even clear to me that the claim is true).  My point was just that, in trying to do the induction, you get a choice of which pair $a_i, b_j$ to "pul out" of the list.  There might be a particularly good choice there.

Comment: What I'd do first is to analyze small $n$.  For $n=2$, I think the claim is clear.  But already for $n=3$ it's not obvious to me.  So, start by fully understanding that case.